# How to insert products automatically

Tags: product, catalog

I need to add new products automatically.
Is there a way to do it by API or something similar?

Comment: There is an import functionality. System->Import/Export.

Comment: Use Magmi otherwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the actual question, yes, Magento has a Web Services API that can be used to do such things. http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html